# What safety precautions should I take on the Appalachian Trail?

Tags: hiking, safety, appalachian-trail

I plan to do a short hike (3-4 days) on the Appalachian Trail in September in Connecticut. What safety precautions should I take?

What wild animals (and wild people) could I encounter?

Comment: The most common hazard in Connecticut would be unpleasant weather, either cold with rain and slush or hot with oppressive humidity. However, in September you stand at least some chance of hitting one of the four or five days a year on which the weather is pleasant.

Comment: [Dangerous people](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-32856626) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some short stretches of the AT in near-by areas of NY state which should be about the same as the AT in CT. The trail is well-marked and well-traveled.

Wildlife is mostly the standard small woodland animals, but there can also be bears. We have not had trouble finding suitable trees for hoisting a bear bag and have not had a problem with that.

The well-traveled part is a mixed blessing. There are lean-tos around, but they may be occupied. I haven't personally had a problem with any people bothering me or any theft or anything, but I also generally hike with a friend or a group, which I think would tend to discourage strangers from causing trouble.